# IllegalStateException: No activity when onStop() method called

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

In the beginning i define three integers

```
public static int button1, buttoncos, buttonmadd;
```

Then i store the value of drawables in them

```
case R.id.blue:
          for (Button currentButton : buttons) {
                currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                button1 = buttoncos = buttonmadd = R.drawable.blue;
            };
          return true;
```

Then in `onDestroy()` and `onPause()`, I write following code

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
    editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
    editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
    editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
    editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
    editor.commit();
}
```

I write nothing in `onStart()`.

Then in `onCreate()` method, I write following code:

```
for (Button currentButton : digitbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(button1);
    }
  for (Button currentButton : memoryfunctions) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttonmadd);
    }
  for (Button currentButton : functionbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttoncos);
    }
    }
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

After i run my application and change themes my app crashes. Here is my logcat:

```
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3625)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3679)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:162)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1091)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStop(FragmentManager.java:1907)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:612)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onStop(ActionBarActivity.java:109)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1211)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5264)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620)
03-17 23:53:38.033: E/AndroidRuntime(15638):    ... 11 more
```

Why am i getting this error.

Comment: Your full `MainActivity` code?

Comment: Its very long would exceed maximum allowed length.

Comment: see answer below: remove `super.onDestroy();` from onPause(); and call `super.onPause();` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `super.onDestroy()` from `onPause()` method and add `super.onPause()` as below...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
    editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
    editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Since you calling `onDestroy()` method of `super` class in `onPause()` method then the `Activity` finishes in before `onStop()` method. So, when `onStop()` method is called according to the activity life-cycle then it can't find any activity...That's why following `Exception` causing...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
```

Comment: Thanx its working there is just ne more problem. When i press middle button on my device to show all apps running in background and then remove my application from there too and then restart it. The style is not restored.

Comment: do you restore the style in onCreate?